# relationship between stongly inductive poset and zorn's lemma

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In appendix A of Prof. Richard Elman's lecture notes [link](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erse/algebra_book.pdf), at first, he gives a proof in Proposition A.3 for an equivalence statement of zorn's lemma, i. e. every nonempty strongly inductive poset has a maximal element . However, I find the proof there has something wrong. Set $\mathfrak{C}$ here contains all chains of $S$. I think there must be something uncorrect in Line 4 starting from 'Let $C \in \mathfrak{C}$'. But I don't know how to fix the problem here. Hope that someone can help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is incorrect. The collection of chains in a partial order is itself a strongly inductive poset, when ordered by $\subseteq$.

By the assumption, this strongly inductive poset has a maximal element, which is, by definition, a maximal chain in the original poset $S$. Since every chain has an upper bound in $S$, so must this maximal chain have an upper bound. But because it is maximal, the upper bound must be an element of the chain and a maximal element of $S$.

Comment: I think the there's something wrong with the construction of $C_0$, since if those $C$ are not sets, we can not use union operation.

Comment: They are chains, so they are sets.

Comment: However the union operation is on the element of a chain, not chains themselves.

Comment: No, it is the union of the chains in the chain-of-chains.

Comment: Thanks very much, now, with your answer I can prove the equivalence on my own, essentials are to prove that $\mathfrak{C}$ is strongly inductive and the the upper bound $x_0$ of $C'$ the maximal of $\mathfrak{C}$ actually belongs to $C'$ itself and it must also be the maximal of the original set $S$. However, I can still not understand the proof in the lecture note, and I can't agree with what you said that the union op. is on chains in the chain-of-chains. Also, I don't know why in the last $x_0$ equals union of the sets in $C'$ and then this is used to prove that $x_0 \in C_0$ .

Comment: I think just use the fact $\{x_0 \} \cup C_0$ is also a chain can prove that the $x_0 \in C_0$.